# How to use webpack-dev-middleware with feathers / express?

Tags: node.js, express, webpack, webpack-dev-server, feathersjs

I'm trying to get a feathersjs app started with a reactjs frontend. Using the `webpack-dev-middleware` and `webpack-hot-middleware`, I should be able to simply extend the feathers app with all this webpack stuff during development. The only problem is always end up getting a feathers 404 page whenever I fetch the js file from webpack.

Currrently, here's my directory structure:

```
/feathers/public/index.html
/feathers/src/app.js
/react/src/index.js
/react/webpack.config.js
/react/develop.js
```

`/feathers/src/app.js` is is default feathers app, serves static files from the public folder.

```
.use('/', serveStatic( app.get('public') ))
```

In `/react/develop.js`, I'm requiring the feathers app and extending it with the webpack middlewares.

```
const app = require('../feathers/src/app');
const config = require('./webpack.config');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

var compiler = webpack(config);

app.use(require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler, {
  publicPath: '/',
  stats: {colors: true},
}));

app.use(require('webpack-hot-middleware')(compiler));

const port = app.get('port');
const server = app.listen(port);
server.on('listening', () =>
  console.log(`Feathers application started on ${app.get('host')}:${port}`)
);
```

Sadly this isn't working at all. For reference, here's my `/react/webpack.config.js`

```
var webpack = require("webpack")

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    'src/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: '/',
    filename: "bundle.js",
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, loader: "babel", exclude: /node_modules/, query: { presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-0'] } },
      { test: /\.(svg|png|jpe?g|gif|ttf|woff2?|eot)$/, loader: 'url?limit=8182' },
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    root: [
      __dirname,
      __dirname + '/src',
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
  ]
}
```

And `/feathers/public/index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>React App</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried messing around with the publicPath stuff but no luck. Any ideas how to get this working? I've spend a solid 2 hours on this and got no where. [Here's a link to the repo I'm working with for more context](https://github.com/ccorcos/feathers-react/).

Answer (score 4):

I see from your repository that you got this to work by including the webpack dev/hot middlewares in the proper place, in [feathers/src/middleware/index.js](https://github.com/ccorcos/feathers-react/blob/master/feathers/src/middleware/index.js#L13-L17) where they will be used before Feathers' notFound middleware returns the 404. **Middleware order matters!**

Exporting a function for this purpose like you did in [react/middleware.js](https://github.com/ccorcos/feathers-react/blob/master/react/middleware.js) is a clean solution to this problem, because it isolates the concern of setting up the webpack middleware from the backend itself (all the webpack stuff stays in the frontend).

Hope this helps anyone else!